# does sorting minimize distance?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, sorting

Say suppose $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume we have a sorting algorithm that sort $x \to X: \{ x_i \}_{i=1}^n = \{ X_i \}_{i=1}^n $

and for every $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$, $X_i \leq X_j$.

The same thing applies to $Y$.

Is it true that $||X-Y||_2^2 \leq ||x-y||_2^2$ ? If yes, prove it. If not, give a counterexample.

Many thanks!

p/s: here is what I got so far: equivalent transformation

$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i -Y_i)^2 \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -y_i)^2$

Comment: Interesting question. I'd really like to know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - Y_i)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - y_i)^2 \iff X_1Y_1 + ... + X_nY_n \geq X_1Y_{\sigma(1)} + ... + X_nY_{\sigma(n)}$ after some expansion and rearrangement, where $\sigma$ represents the permutation of $[n]$ corresponding to the unsorted lists. More specifically, we let $\sigma$ be such that $\forall k \in [n]$, $(X_k, Y_{\sigma(k)})$ is equivalent to a unique pair $(x_i,y_i)$. $X_1Y_1 + ... + X_nY_n \geq X_1Y_{\sigma(1)} + ... + X_nY_{\sigma(n)}$ follows immediately from the rearrangement inequality (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), since $X_1 \leq ... \leq X_n$ and $Y_1 \leq ... \leq Y_n$.

Comment: should the sign read $\leq$ in the first and second equations or am I really missing something? sorry... it flips sign because minus sign. saw it!

Comment: great - no problem!

Comment: last question: is it the optimal bound w.r.t. the permutation?

Comment: do you mean the inequality $X_1Y_1 + ... + X_nY_n \geq X_1Y_{\sigma(1)} + ... + X_nY_{\sigma(n)}$? And what do you mean by "with respect to the permutation?"

Comment: yeah well, your proof is right. i have no complain about it. look fantastic. just about to tick the best answer, except for the missing piece: "does sorting minimize distance?" so what i'm asking is: does the sorting yield minimum $L^2$-distance between $x$ and $y$? 

p/s: never mind, i read over the theorem again. it really says for \textit{every} permutation. thanks alot!

Comment: yup, sorting should yield the minimum $L^2$-distance. no problem :)